# select where en un campo hayan dos comas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en `mysql` con un campo llamado `coordenadas` con información más o menos así:

> -75.99699,4.0537896 // 1 coma
>    -76.01502,4.085585,1390.0 // 2 comas 
>  
>    -76.478325,3.9739854 // 1 coma 
>    -76.0716,4.1359963,1751.0 // 2 comas

Quisiera poder hacer un `select` en donde me traiga solo los `records` que tengan **dos (2)** *comas* "**,**" ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: con mysql no creo que se pueda, por que no lo haces con un leguaje?

Comment: Quiero ver si es posible hacerlo directamente desde la consulta sin tener que `parsear` todos los datos por `php`

Comment: Detalle aparte, pero sería bueno separar cada dato en su propia columna propiamente identificada, en vez de tener que manejar las comas.

Comment: @sstan si, solo que fue un mal procedimiento en un "data import" a una tabla mediante un csv, u.u

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podes hacer algo como:

`SELECT * FROM ejemplo WHERE coordenadas LIKE '%,%,%';`

Comment: Jaja, no sé porque no se me había ocurrido algo así tan simple, muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar la expresión 'LIKE', la cual te permite seleccionar registros según le indiques, quedaría así:

```
SELECT
tabla.coordenadas
FROM
tabla
WHERE
tabla.cordenadas LIKE '%,%,%';
```

Donde el carácter % significa que encuentre cualquier numero, luego una coma, luego de nuevo cualquier numero, luego la segunda coma y cualquier otro numero finalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar Like:

```
Select * from tabla where campo like ['%,%,%'];
```